# Trouble setting up Node.js application on production server from Github repo

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, github

I am trying to setup my Node.js application on production server, but after I run command: `sudo npm install --production` I am keep getting an error:

> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/var/www/movicritRepo/code/nodejsAPI/node_modules/express-session' -> '/var/www/movicritRepo/code/nodejsAPI/node_modules/.express-session.DELETE'

My directory is a Github cloned repository. When I use `ls -l` command on node_modules there is no express-session map. I am really stuck here... Can anyone help me please? Thank you in beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's an existing `node_modules/.express-session.DELETE` directory that should be removed:

```
rm -fr node_modules/.express-session.DELETE
```

It may not show up in the output of `ls` because its name starts with a period, but you can use `ls -a` to show it:

```
ls -al node_modules
```